# How to use cygwin 1.5 default authentication mechanism on cygwin 1.7

Tags: authentication, cygwin

In cyg-version 1.5 all enable accounts were listed in /etc/passwd but in the latest cyg-version, a direct authentication against the windows user db is done.

So my question is how key authentication can be configured in the latest cyg-version and if it is possible to use key authentication with the new default authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

User authentication was always versus windows user database. There was no password stored on `/etc/passwd`: the second field was never used.

The scope of `/etc/passwd` was to link the `cygwin user name` in the first field to the `windows user name` and `SID` in the fifth field.
If the cywgin and windows name are the same there is no no need anymore of
`/etc/passwd`

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping-how

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using cygwin for the first time. I got a machine with cygwin 1.7.5 already installed on it. But it is still not clear to me about how can I use both mechanisms at the same time.